# Trying to take make fields mandatory `lightning-input-field`

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system, javascript-controller

I'm trying to make fields are mandatory to fill, but its not working with  `lightning-input-field`

How to achieve it with  `lightning-input-field`

```
 <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Sytems__c">

    <template for:each={defaultFields} for:item="field">
              <lightning-input-field required class="requiredField" key={field.name} variant="label-stacked" name={field.name} field-name={field.name}
                onchange={handleNineFieldValueChange}>
              </lightning-input-field>
            </template>
    
        <lightning-button variant="brand" title="submit" onclick={validateFields} label="Save">
        </lightning-button> 

    </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

.JS Code below

```
validateFields(){

        const isInputsCorrect = [...this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-field')]
            .reduce((validSoFar, inputField) => {
                inputField.reportValidity();
                return validSoFar && inputField.checkValidity();
            }, true);
        if (isInputsCorrect) {
         //perform success logic

        }
    }
```

ERROR

```
Uncaught TypeError: t.checkValidity is not a function throws
```

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the documentation:

**Requiring a Value for a Field**

> lightning-input-field supports requiredness specified on the server and
> client. In record forms, a required field is displayed with a red
> asterisk next to the field label. If you interact with a required
> field but don't enter a value, an error message is displayed below the
> field. Similarly, if you don't interact with a required field and try
> to submit the form, an error message is displayed.
>
> To make an input field required on the server, mark the field Required
> in Setup. Input fields set as required on the server are universally
> required, to be displayed with a red asterisk wherever the input
> fields are used. For more information, see Require Field Input to
> Ensure Data Quality in Salesforce help.
>
> To make an input field required on the client only, include the
> required attribute in lightning-input-field. Use this attribute if you
> want to require a value in a field before the form can be submitted,
> and the field isn't marked required in Setup. If the field doesn't
> have a value, the component's client-side validation catches the error
> before the form data is submitted to the server.
>
> The client-side required setting and validation for requiredness is
> unrelated to the Required setting on the server. Note that you can't
> set required to false to disable the required setting on the server.
> The required field is still displayed with a red asterisk.

for this to work, you need to add the `required` attribute to the component.

Furthermore, if you need to add custom validation, you will need to add your custom handlers when the form is submitted, and manually perform the operation. You can achieve this by Overriding Default Behaviors of the record-edit-form as specified in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation)

Comment: Hey I want to do it in custom validation because I'm not using standard submit button so that's why, here I'm using custom save method to save data also

Comment: Please refer to the documentation, how to achieve this is pretty straightforward and well documented, checkValidity is reserved for `lightning-input` components not for `lightning-input-field`